# Duplicating storyboard views depending on Account credentials

Tags: swift, permissions, storyboard, user-accounts

I am currently writing an iOS application in Swift, and upon login, you are given 1 of 3 different account credentials: New User, Current Member, and Admin Member. A New User is defined as an account that has not been placed into a group, a Current Member is defined as an account that is currently in a group, and an Admin member is defined as an account that is the admin for a group.

I want to try to keep the UI the same for all accounts, to keep usability high for every user. I see 2 options, I can either branch 3 different storyboard routes from login and design them to be the same, or I can design 1 flexible storyboard that loads views based on permissions.

I would like to do option #2, however my question is: Is there the functionality in Swift to run a single, agile storyboard view that changes it's elements based off of permissions? Or would I have better luck creating three different storyboard branches?

***Edit:*** To clarify, all data pertaining to each account will be drawn from a Firebase web application, so the UI itself will not have to worry about storing and fetching data based on account permissions from it's own memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "agile storyboard", but you can have your storyboard to include all visual elements for all users and then do programatic adaptation, weather it's to hide/show some views, change colors etc.

However if your views are very different you may opt to create common visual elements in *.xib files and then load them programmatically as needed for a specific user type.

Comment: The application itself is a relatively simple 3 tab bar view, but for instance, new members would not have access to the functionality of one of the bars tabs, so when I say "Agile", I want to be able to adapt that specific view based on login permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you can keep the login permissions for them and depending on that, show it through hiding different objects in your one viewcontroller. If it's a tab bar, through the login permissions, you can hide the specific bar that can't be accessed by the NEW USER.